# NestJS - Redirect user from guard when check fails

Tags: redirect, nestjs

I've added some simple, working login functionality to a NestJS app I'm building. I now want to block access to certain routes for logged out users, so I've added a simple `AuthGuard`, which looks like this;

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    public canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        if (typeof request.session.authenticated !== "undefined" && request.session.authenticated === true) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works in the way it blocks the user from accessing routes the guard is applied to, but in doing so it just shows this JSON response;

```json
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden resource"
}
```

What I want is the user to be redirected to the login page when the guard fails. I've tried replacing the `return false` with `response.redirect("/auth/login");` and although it works, in the console I get messages

`(node:11526) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

`(node:11526) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

So although it works, it doesn't seem to be the best solution.

The route the guard is called on is as follows btw:

```js
@Get()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard)
@Render("index")
public index() {
    return {
        user: {},
    };
}
```

Is it at all possible to properly redirect a user after the guard fails?

Answer (score 14):

You can achieve what you want using both guard and filter. Throw an UnauthorizedException from your guard and handle the exception from filter to redirect. Here is a such filter:

```ts
import {
 ExceptionFilter,
 Catch,
 ArgumentsHost,
 HttpException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';
import { UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
   
@Catch(UnauthorizedException)
export class ViewAuthFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();
 
    response.status(status).redirect('/admins');
  }
}
```

below is how to use it:

```ts
@Get('/dashboard')
@UseGuards(JwtGuard)
@UseFilters(ViewAuthFilter)
@Render('dashboard/index')
dashboard() {
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, just 2 things I did different.
1) `@Catch(ForbiddenException)` for this type of error
2) The Browser was completely omitting the status so I put it in the redirect call: `response.redirect('/auth/login', status);`

Answer (score 2):

It seems very strange that an endpoint that is supposed to return a JSON, returns a redirection to HTML content.

Though, if you want to manage how your exceptions are handled with user-friendly custom content, I suggest you take a look at exception filters:

https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Directly pasted from the documentation of nestjs, here is an explicit example:

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common';
import { HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse();
    const request = ctx.getRequest();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ExceptionFilter` as suggested above is in my opinion not the best solution, as this would filter all `UnauthorizedException`s, even those you don't want to redirect.

The errors in console are because NestJS does not know the response was finished by your `response.redirect()`.

From a guard (class with CanActivate interface) you cannot finish the response directly, but you can force NestJS to finish the response right after by returning false or by throwing a `HttpException`.
Returning false would result in NestJS trying to send a 403 Forbidden response, which is not what you want, you want to return 302 Found status for redirection.

Unfortunatelly there is no built in Exception for response with 302 Found HTTP status. But you can create one.

**found.exception.ts:**

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from "@nestjs/common";

export class FoundException extends HttpException {
  constructor(message: string = "Found") {
    super(message, HttpStatus.FOUND);
  }
}
```

In your guard you must then first set the Location header for the redirect and then throw the above FoundException to return a 302 HTTP status.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    public canActivate(
        context: ExecutionContext,
    ): boolean {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        if (typeof request.session.authenticated !== "undefined" && request.session.authenticated === true) {
            return true;
        }

        response.setHeader("location", "/auth/login");          // <---
        throw new FoundException("Redirecting you to login...") // <---
    }
}
```